# Need Page Number on Sub report to start from 2 in SSRS

Tags: sql, sql-server, reporting-services, ssrs-2008, report

I have a main report and a subreport in the main report. The main report is like a cover page so I need to start the page number on the subreport from 2 and end with number of pages in the subreport +1 (for the main report). i.e; if My subreport has 10 pages it should start with 2 of 11. I have googled and all the resources tell me how to start from page 1. Thanks for your time and help in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's simple,

```
= "Page " & Globals!PageNumber + 1 & " of " & Globals!TotalPages + 1
```

This will give you *Page 2 of 11*.

The fact remains the same that there are only 10 pages.

Answer (score 0):

I guess its fairly simple, In your textbox in page footer of your subreport where you are showing page number, use the following expression

```
= Globals!PageNumber + 1 & " of " & Globals!TotalPages + 1
```

Comment: Thanks for the help @M.Ali. Fairly new to ssrs so getting stuck at simple things.